# Why is the kernel dying in my Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

I am trying to run a CNN model VGG16. While running after 2 or 3 epochs, it suddenly shows an error message saying

> Kernel Restarting
>
> The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of error message]

What's going on?

Comment: Reload the page or restart the jupyter notebook from terminal

Comment: I did it many times but don't work.